# Angular 6: How to bind props between 2 objects? (service and local)

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, data-binding

I use a service with an object:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService{
  public myObject: AClass;

  constructor() {
    this.myObject= new AClass();
  }
}
```

I injected this in some components.

one of them is parent and the rest of them are children.
I don't want to use @Input() and @Output(), because are lots of props in children components.

In every child's contructor I have this:

```
public localObject;

constructor(myService: MyService) {
    this.localObject = myService.myObject
}
```

localObject is used in html, for example:

`<input [(value)]="localObject.name" />` etc...

problem is:

if in parent I update service model (after an api call or something else), localObjects from children are not updated. (not binded) and ""'s value isn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by appending an access modifier to your service dependency :

**Public**

```js
constructor(public myService: MyService) {}
```

```html
<input [(value)]="myService.myObject.name" />
```

**Private**

```js
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
get myObject() { return this.myService.myObject; }
```

```html
<input [(value)]="myObject.name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Better will be to use `Subject/BehaviorSubject` or some sort of Observable

One approach will be like

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService{
  public subjectOne;
  public myObject: AClass;

  constructor() {
    this.myObject= new AClass();
    this.subjectOne = new BehaviorSubject<AClass>(this.myObject);
  }
}

public localObject;

constructor(myService: MyService) {
    myService.subjectOne.subscribe(data => this.localObject = data);
}

changeHandler(event: Event) {
    myService.subjectOne.next(event.target.value);
}

<input [value]="localObject.name" (change)="changeHandler($event)" />
```

And similarly for object places you have subscribe this subject and listen from change or broadcast changes